# Redefinir credenciais do Git pelo terminal Linux

Tags: linux, git, permissões

Utilizava anteriormente outro usuário do Git em meu computador pessoal. Editei o config user com o nome e email de usuário novos, porém quando pressiono `git push` me ocorre:

```
remote: permissão para nomedeusuárionovo / repo.git negada para nomedeusuárioantigo.
fatal: não foi possível acessar ' https://github.com/nomedeusuárionovo/repo.git/ ':
o URL solicitado retornou o erro: 403
```

Quando o mesmo erro já me ocorreu utilizando Windows, porém para resolvê-lo bastou **editar as Credenciais de Usuário no Painel de Controle, porém a solução não se aplica ao Linux**.

Sistema Operacional utilizado para reproduzir o erro:
*Linux Mint 19.3 - Cinnamon*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema indo em "**Senhas e Chaves**", encontrando a opção "**vscode-github.login/account**", clicando com o botão direito e **excluindo-a**.

A próxima vez que efetuei o push, o github redefiniu a autenticação.